# numpy array subsetting error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a numpy sparse matrix A1 of type

```
 scipy.sparse.dok.dok_matrix
```

with integer values. I'm trying to use it to subset another integer matrix A2 of type

```
 numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix
```

by

```
 A2[A1>0]
```

Both of them have shape (1,10000). Although it works well to use

```
 A1[A1>0]
```

I get the following error:

```
>> A2[A1>0]

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-250-19959d659dc5>", line 1, in <module>
  edge_counts[nodes>0]

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 284, in __getitem__
out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexError` is telling that `A1 > 0` is not an object compatible with indexing.
You can investigate easily with:

```
In []: type(A1 > 0)
Out[]: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

And you can turn in to a `bool` array by converting A1 to an array first, using `toarray()`:

```
In []: type(A1.toarray() > 0)
Out[]: numpy.ndarray
```

Then `A2[A1.toarray() > 0]` should work just fine.